# Getting error 'SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/password_reset/' when using mailgun sandbox for django in python

Tags: python, django, mailgun

I'm trying to send password reset email using mailgun sandbox for django with python (PyCharm app) and I get this error when I try resetting my password.

in settings.py,

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.mailgun.org"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Where I have user and password in as environmental variables.

The error I am getting is

SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/password_reset/
(550, b'5.7.1 Relaying denied', 'webmaster@localhost')

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_reset/

```
Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 222, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 235, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 323, in save
    self.send_mail(
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 273, in send_mail
    email_message.send()
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 109, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\PycharmProjects\user_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 125, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "C:\Users\dmsql\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 871, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/password_reset/
Exception Value: (550, b'5.7.1 Relaying denied', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

Comment: always put full error message (startingat word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are ther useful information.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - especially what you get with `os.environ.get()`. It can gives `None` if it can't find `environmental variables`.

Comment: @furas I did the print() to find if they get the right values and they do! So they can find environmental variables.... 
I've also added the full error message above!

Answer (score 0):

> SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/password_reset/ (550, b'5.7.1 Relaying denied', 'webmaster@localhost')

In your settings.py, you need to set Django's [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) to a valid sender address for your Mailgun account. If you don't set it, Django defaults to `webmaster@localhost`, which Mailgun doesn't allow.

While you're at it, you probably also want to set Django's [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-SERVER_EMAIL), which defaults to `root@localhost` and will cause similar problems on admin emails.